# Using 'relational' queries with GORM/GO

Tags: postgresql, go, grails-orm

## The question

The documentation on GORM is a little sparse and we don't get some of the concepts working - the 'has many'. https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html

I've added my conceptual issues as FIXME in the code.

If anyone knows how to solve these, I'd like to add this to the GORM documentation on later.

## The code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
    "log"
)

// User has many CreditCards, UserID is the foreign key
type CreditCardUser struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string
    CreditCards []CreditCard `gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID"`
}

type CreditCard struct {
    gorm.Model
    Number string
    Bank   string
    UserID uint
}

func main() {
    //https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        "localhost", 5432, "postgres", "52436c7a7d852f6aee3658e4150adf9782a5e418", "serverprovisioning")
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
        //Logger: logruslogger.Debug(), // FIXME https://github.com/onrik/gorm-logrus

        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info), // FIXME expose this with environment variable DB_LOG_LEVEL Info/Warn/Error/Trace
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    db.Migrator().DropTable(&CreditCardUser{}, &CreditCard{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&CreditCardUser{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&CreditCard{})

    // https://github.com/harranali/gorm-relationships-examples/tree/main/has-many
    // https://gist.github.com/jtbonhomme/ff6db22b8dcac7dd9349e26bad002fb1
    fmt.Println("About to create a relational object")
    // insert new record
    db.Create(&CreditCardUser{Name: "mrFlux", CreditCards: []CreditCard{{Number: "1234567898", Bank: "FinFisher"}, {Number: "345657881", Bank: "MaxedOut Limited"}}})
    db.Create(&CreditCardUser{Name: "sirTuxedo", CreditCards: []CreditCard{{Number: "999999999", Bank: "FinFisher"}, {Number: "2342", Bank: "Bankxter"}}})
    db.Create(&CreditCardUser{Name: "missFraudinger", CreditCards: []CreditCard{{Number: "999999999", Bank: "FinFisher"}}})
    db.Create(&CreditCardUser{Name: "happyUser"})

    //////////// 1 - get all credit card records of user 'mrFlux' ////////////
    fmt.Println("---1-----------------------------------")
    creditCardsOfFlux := []CreditCardUser{}
    db.Preload("CreditCards").Where("name=?", "mrFlux").Find(&creditCardsOfFlux)
    fmt.Println("The credit cards of mrFlux are: ", creditCardsOfFlux)

    //////////// 2 - get all FinFisher Credit Card records of user 'mrFlux' ////////////
    fmt.Println("---2-----------------------------------")
    finFisherCreditCards := []CreditCard{}
    // FIXME this does not work
    db.Preload("CreditCardUser").Preload("CreditCard").Find(&finFisherCreditCards)
    fmt.Println("mrFlux's FinFisher card(s) are: ", finFisherCreditCards)

    //////////// 3 - update wrong creditcard number of the sirTuxedo's Bankxter card number from 2342 to 23422342 ////////////
    fmt.Println("---3-----------------------------------")
    // FIXME no clue yet

    //////////// 4 -  list all user(s) with a credit card from 'FinFisher' Bank ////////////
    fmt.Println("---4-----------------------------------")
    // FIXME no clue yet

    //////////// 5 - drop all credit card relations for all users with a fraudy 999999999 card number from any bank ////////////
    fmt.Println("---5-----------------------------------")
    // FIXME no clue yet


    fmt.Println("/About to create a relational object")
}
```

## console output

```
---1-----------------------------------

2022/07/29 19:35:25 C:/Users/joschie/GolandProjects/awesomeProject/main.go:55
[1.000ms] [rows:2] SELECT * FROM "credit_cards" WHERE "credit_cards"."user_id" = 1 AND "credit_cards"."deleted_at" IS NULL

2022/07/29 19:35:25 C:/Users/joschie/GolandProjects/awesomeProject/main.go:55
[2.999ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM "credit_card_users" WHERE name='mrFlux' AND "credit_card_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL
The credit cards of mrFlux are: [{{1 2022-07-29 19:35:25.935651 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.935651 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} mrFlux [{{1 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363
+0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 1234567898 FinFisher 1} {{2 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 345657881 MaxedOut Limited 1}]}]
---2-----------------------------------

2022/07/29 19:35:25 C:/Users/joschie/GolandProjects/awesomeProject/main.go:62 CreditCard: unsupported relations for schema CreditCard; CreditCardUser: unsupported relations for schema CreditCard
[1.000ms] [rows:5] SELECT * FROM "credit_cards" WHERE "credit_cards"."deleted_at" IS NULL
mrFlux's FinFisher card(s) are: [{{1 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 1234567898 FinFisher 1} {{2 2022-07-29 19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29
19:35:25.937363 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 345657881 MaxedOut Limited 1} {{3 2022-07-29 19:35:25.942696 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.942696 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 999999999 Fin
Fisher 2} {{4 2022-07-29 19:35:25.942696 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.942696 +0200 CEST {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 2342 Bankxter 2} {{5 2022-07-29 19:35:25.946875 +0200 CEST 2022-07-29 19:35:25.946875 +0200 CEST {00
01-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}} 999999999 FinFisher 3}]
---3-----------------------------------
---4-----------------------------------
---5-----------------------------------
---6-----------------------------------
/About to create a relational object

Process finished with the exit code 0
```

## Solution

There is still one issue with the problem 3 and we've added a problem 7 as well which was not in the original list.

We also are using CASCADE now as it seems to make modifying the data easier:

```
`gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
```

Here is the source:

https://github.com/qknight/gorm-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go-gorm` documentation provides just enough examples to show how something works. Personally, I do agree that there could be more examples, but at the same time, there are a lot of combinations to cover in examples.

One important thing to remember is always to try to construct a SQL query by using `go-gorm` functions. Try to work out how a raw SQL query should do the job, then convert it into `go-gorm` functions.

**second task**

You can either load just the cards with a `Joins` function

```
finFisherCreditCards := []CreditCard{}  
db.Joins("INNER JOIN credit_card_users ccu ON ccu.id = credit_cards.user_id").Where("ccu.name = ?", "mrFlux").Find(&finFisherCreditCards)
```

or load the user with just the `FinFisher` credit card records

```
user := CreditCardUser{}
db.Preload("CreditCards", "bank = ?", "FinFisher").First(&user, "name =?", "mrFlux")
```

**third task**

Use a subquery (to select a user ID for `sirTuxedo` ) and `Where` functions to get the object you want, then you can [update just one field](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-single-column).

```
db.Model(&CreditCard{}).Where("name = ? AND user_id = ?", "Bankxter", db.Model(&CreditCardUser{}).Where("name = ?", "sirTuxedo").Select("id")).Update("number", "23422342")
```

**fourth task**

If you just want to find users, use `Joins`, `Where`, and `Find` functions. You can use `Preload` here if you want all of their credit cards with them.

```
users := []CreditCardUsers{}
db.Joins("INNER JOIN credit_cards cc ON cc.user_id = credit_card_users.id").Where("cc.bank = ?", "FinFisher").Find(&users)
```

**fifth task**

Even though there is a relationship, I presume that here you don't care about users, but just want to delete the fraudulent cards. This is then just a conditional delete operation (`Where` and `Delete` functions).

```
db.Where("number = ?", "9999999999").Delete(&CreditCard{})
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Everything makes sense what you write. The only thing which did not work yet is the third task, I get: [0.365ms] [rows:0] UPDATE "credit_cards" SET "number"='23422342',"updated_at"='2022-08-01 13:40:52.819' WHERE (ccu.name = 'sirTuxedo' AND credit_cards.bank = 'Bankxter') AND "credit_cards"."deleted_at" IS NULL
Couldn't update credit card number:  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ccu" (SQLSTATE 42P01)

Comment: I've updated that code by using a subquery instead of a `Joins` function. The other approach would be to just write an update SQL query and execute it with an `Exec` function.

Comment: I get ---3-----------------------------------

2022/08/02 09:19:19 /app/main.go:82 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ccu" (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[0.444ms] [rows:0] UPDATE "credit_cards" SET "number"='23422342',"updated_at"='2022-08-02 09:19:19.464' WHERE (ccu.name = 'sirTuxedo' AND credit_cards.bank = 'Bankxter') AND "credit_cards"."deleted_at" IS NULL
Couldn't update credit card number:  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ccu" (SQLSTATE 42P01) from your new query.

Comment: I've updated the question and linked this repo now: https://github.com/qknight/gorm-examples